# Breaking a div's content into multiple columns if is too large

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

Working on a display for a kitchen, and trying to come up with an idea of how to break ticket displays into multiple columns when they are over a certain size.  The cart objects can be widely different in amount of content they contain, but I don't want the divs displaying them to end up being longer than the screen size, ideally, I would like to keep them about 50% of the screen size to allow for multiple rows to be shown on the screen at the same time.
Here is the display as I have it currently:
[image]

When these tickets end up being more than 50% of the screen height, I would like to break them into a new div that sits next to the 1st one, and continues the list, working with thymeleaf/css.  This is how it is being displayed currently:

```
<div id="orders" style="margin-top:5vh; overflow-y:auto; margin-right:20vw; display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap;">


<a th:each="ticket: ${openTickets}"
   style="text-decoration:none; border-style:solid; margin:3px; width:18%; height:fit-content;"
   th:href="@{'/administrative/kitchenView/'+${ticket.id}+'/complete'}">
    <div th:text="${ticket.customerName}" style="text-align:center; border-style:solid;"></div>
    <div style="text-align:center" th:if="${ticket.orderSentTimestamp}"
         th:text="${ticket.timeSinceCartSent()}"></div>

    <!--display each entreeItem-->
    <div th:if="${ticket.hasEntrees()}" style="border-style:solid; ">
        <div>Entrees:</div>
        <div class="itemLine" th:each="entree : ${ticket.entrees}">
            <div style="margin:2px;">
                <div style="text-decoration:underline overline; text-align:center;">
                    <span th:text="${entree.name}"></span>
                    <span th:if="${entree.hasQuantity()}" th:text="'- Qty: '+${entree.quantity}"></span>
                </div>
                <div th:if="${entree.hasItemChoice()}">
                    <div class="itemDetailLine" th:text="'-'+${entree.itemChoice.getName()}"></div>
                </div>
                <div th:if="${entree.hasTemp()}">
                    <div class="itemDetailLine"
                         th:text="'-Temp: '+${entree.temp.getTempDisplayName()}"></div>
                </div>
                <div th:if="${entree.hasItemSize()}">
                    <div class="itemDetailLine" th:text="'-Size: '+${entree.itemSize.getDescription()}"></div>
                </div>
                <div th:if="${entree.hasItemToppings()}">
                    <div class="itemDetailLine" th:each="topping : ${entree.itemToppings}"
                         th:text="'-'+${topping.getDescription()}"></div>
                </div>
                <div th:if="${entree.hasFoodOptions()}">
                    <div class="itemDetailLine" th:each="option : ${entree.foodOptions}"
                         th:text="'-'+${option.getOptionDescription()}"></div>
                </div>
                <div th:if="${entree.hasSides()}">
                    <div class="itemDetailLine" th:each="side : ${entree.sides}"
                         th:text="'-'+${side.getSideDishName()}"></div>
                </div>
                <div th:if="${entree.hasSpecialRequest()}">
                    <div class="itemDetailLine" th:text="'-Special Request: '+${entree.specialRequest}"></div>
                </div>
                <div th:if="${entree.hasForName()}">
                    <div class="itemDetailLine" th:text="'-For: '+${entree.forName}"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--end of entreeItem display-->

    <!--Display each side item-->
    <div th:if="${ticket.hasSides()}" style="border-style:solid; ">
        <div>Sides:</div>
        <div class="itemLine" th:each="side: ${ticket.sides}">
            <div style="margin:2px;">
                <div style="text-decoration:underline overline; text-align:center;">
                    <span th:text="'-'+${side.name}"></span>
                    <span th:if="${side.hasQuantity()}" th:text="'- Qty: '+${side.quantity}"></span>
                </div>
                <div th:if="${side.hasItemToppings()}">
                    <div class="itemDetailLine" th:text="'-'+${topping.getDescription()}"
                         th:each="topping : ${side.itemToppings}"></div>
                </div>
                <div th:if="${side.hasSpecialRequest()}">
                    <div class="itemDetailLine" th:text="'-Special Request: '+${side.specialRequest}"></div>
                </div>
                <div th:if="${side.hasForName()}">
                    <div class="itemDetailLine" th:text="'-For: '+${side.forName}"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Why wouldn't use an existing responsive framework, for example, [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)? There are exactly classes for a situation like yours. [Card grouping](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/card/#card-layout) will give you idea on how they did it and if you don't want 3rd party framework, at least you able to see how to accomplish this.